# Eliminating lines on a scanned photo (from a slide)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photos, scanning

I am restoring an old photo for my father and am having some trouble. The photo was an old slide and no matter how many times and how many ways I scanned it, lines going across the picture always appeared. I want to remove them but I can't figure out how. Any advice?

Comment: You might attempt combining the areas that are line free from multiple scans if the lines don't always appear in the same place as that would mean they aren't part of the slide. And if so, you most likely need a better scanner.

Comment: Are the lines that appear always in the same orientation?  If you rotate the image 90 degrees in the scanner, are the resulting lines also changed?  If so, and you add the two images together (typically in different layers in your photo-editing software), you may be able to make them cancel.  Your result may have only dots where the two lines crossed, where previously you had whole lines of missing content.  Using the "healing brush" feature of your photo-editor may allow you to quickly fix this -- YMMV.  

Consider getting a better scanner.

Comment: See if your scanner has a [descreen/moiré removal feature](http://www.creativepro.com/article/scanning-101-no-more-moir-), else [use software](http://graphicssoft.about.com/cs/photoshop/ht/apsremovemoire.htm) to remove it.